# check class for property and type

Tags: haxe

Got a class with a method that takes an object and loops through it, assigning the values of the object to the class.  This can happen quite a bit in the application and I was wondering if there is an efficient and preferably language agnostic syntax to validate the property name of the object exists and confirm the value type before assigning to the class?  I'm going to need to export this code to at least flash and javascript, possibly others to follow later.  I need to keep the method generic because it lives in a base class.  Something along the lines below:

```
public function updateProperties(propsObj:Object):void {
  for (var prop in propsObj) {
    if (/* this has prop && typeof propsObj[prop] == typeof this[prop] */) {
      this[prop] = propsObj[prop];
    }
  }
}
```

New to Haxe, so I'm having some trouble finding the family of methods for this kind of thing.  Reflect seems to have methods close to what I'm looking for, but a lot of the methods look like they may be overkill for what I need, was hoping for some insight.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work.

```
public function updateProperties(props:Dynamic) {
  for (prop in Reflect.fields(props)) {
    if (Reflect.hasField(this, prop)) {
      Reflect.setProperty(this, prop, Reflect.getProperty(props, prop));
    } else {
      trace("cannot set property " + prop + " on " + this);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you figured it out... Reflect.setProperty() is similar to Refelct.setField(), but does a bit of extra checking in case you're dealing with a haxe property (eg `var myProp(get_myProp,set_myProp):String`).  If you know for sure that you'll only have simple variables, not properties, then Reflect.setField() might be slightly faster.

Comment: You can get the type with `Type.typeof` and compare the results with `Type.enumEq` (because the resulting values are enums).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  In this case I have no idea what types of properties might get set since this method will be common to almost all components.  Good to know about setProperty though for less pervasive functions.